# What is the reason for underexposure in my film photographs?

Tags: exposure, film, troubleshooting, metering

Thanks to all the [quality](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18560/what-should-one-look-for-when-buying-a-used-film-camera) [answers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18688/how-important-is-lack-of-color-matrix-metering-and-100-viewfinder-in-nikon-f100) I [got](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19590/what-does-it-mean-to-mount-slide-film-for-processing) here that helped me to buy a film camera. I got my first roll of film processed and printed.

The print results are not as pleasing as looking at the slides through a loupe (50mm lens). One example is [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vikask/6854981797/in/set-72157629094622173/). It is underexposed and has a purple tint. This is not the only one, all photos have similar characteristic.

Details and settings:

- Camera: Nikon F100
- Film: Velvia 50
- Metering: Matrix

I want to know the reason for underexposed and purple tinted photos. And what should I do to avoid this.

Comment: Are all the photos on this film of snow? If so, snow pics should generally be 'overexposed' by the cameras meter by 1 or 2 stops as the camera is trying to make the snow look mid-grey, not white

Comment: The blue cast is also typical of snow.

Comment: @Dreamager is right, its the same issue you have on a non-film DSLR with snow.

Comment: And a lot of the "blue cast" in the snow is probably quite real. Light _is_ blueish in wintertime in northern latitudes, you eyes just happen to be very good at auto-whitebalancing it out for you so you think it is white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purple cast is typically Velvia - learn to love it, embrace it and you'll get some stunning results. The underexposure is a compound of two things - firstly your camera is compensating and trying to make the snow appear as a mid-tone, and secondly Velvia is known for being a bit slow, many people rate it at ISO 40 or even ISO 32.

When shooting Velvia remember that you've only got 4 stops of latitude, in order to record this scene properly I'd meter the snow with a spot-meter, and then pull this up to the highlight by over-exposing that by 2 stops. You'll then get far more detail in the dark areas, and your snow will be sparkly white.

Comment: They don't call it DisneyChrome for nothing.